# phpmyadmin - browse table option grayed out but browse distinct values shows table data

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm making a website using php and using phpmyadmin manage mysql data. For some reason some of my tables as the "Browse" tab disabled. The table has data due to showing it on my website and when I insert a new record, I can browse the table usually for about an hour or so with the old insterts appearing as well with the new entry. Then it's grayed out again. I have another table that is working well though. Also not that when you select the table you want to manage then select "Browse Distinct Values", you can see the table data for that id. Any thoughts on this? I'm using iPage as a host which it's my first time with them. Thanks

Comment: whats the version of you phpmayadmin?

Comment: SHOW WARNINGS; SHOW STATUS LIKE "%slow%"; SHOW STATUS LIKE "%connec%"; SHOW STATUS LIKE "%wait%"; SHOW STATUS LIKE "%load%";

Comment: phpMyAdmin - 2.8.0.1

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey

When I ran that I got
Com_load = 0
Com_preload_keys = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status = not started

SHOW WARNINGS;# Rows: 1
SHOW STATUS LIKE  "%slow%";# Rows: 2
SHOW STATUS LIKE  "%connec%";# Rows: 14
SHOW STATUS LIKE  "%wait%";# Rows: 12
SHOW STATUS LIKE  "%load%";

Comment: Is it worth installing my own phpmyadmin? Looks like this version is way outdated.

Comment: Considering PHPMyAdmin version 4.0.1 is going to be deprecated in the near future (April 2017), you really, really should be upgrading to *at minimum* version 4.4.15 , using PhpMyAdmin version 2.8 is just not going to help you at all. No idea if it relates to this specific issue but its symptomatic of wider issues of using outdated and insecure code. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest upgrading your phpMyAdmin installation. 2.8.0 is approximately 10 years old and there are a host of reasons why it might not be working properly, but aren't really worth trying to figure out why until you try an updated version (if you really like 2.8.0, for some reason, just install a newer version in a different folder to test). It could be that a PHP function is deprecated, or changed the output order; it could be that MySQL changed something or the library that allows PHP and MySQL to communicate had a bug. That version of phpMyAdmin may have had a bug (although nothing like this sounds familiar). I'm surprised it even works with a modern MySQL installation; I would have thought the table structure and authentication plugin changes in MySQL would have left version 2 unable to even load from a modern MySQL server.

I have no idea what the problem actually is, but I think the first step toward resolving it is to indeed update your phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Click the icon to the left of the table to open the list of columns, select all columns, and click "Browse" next to the text "with selected". Then, click the edit button in the sql code at the top of the page, and paste:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC`

This will make the default browse view for that table sort the table by COLUMN_NAME in descending order, overwriting the corrupt default sort.

Comment: The Browse option is not appearing next to "with selected." But when I did use that icon that you mentioned, my table showed up. So if click on the table name on the left hand side, then I can't see my table data. I'm confused.

Comment: What version phpmyadmin are you using.  I am using Version  4.6.4 .    Only thing I can recomment is you look at privilieges and make sure you have "Check All" selected in the "Global Privileges" box.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Operations" tab and in the bottom you will find the maintenance options. Try "check table" and then the "defragmenting" option. The defragmenting worked for me after check table showed no errors.